# GAE require model property iff another has a certain value?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In GAE's `db.Model` properties, we have a `required` parameter that disallows an entity of that model from being created without a value for that property.

e.g.:

```
class user(db.Model):
    isFromUK = db.BoolProperty(required = True)
    fromCounty = db.StringProperty()
```

How can I do essentially `required = True` on `fromCounty` iff the `isFromUK == True`?

I am aware this may not be possible directly in GAE implementation ([I have not found a way in docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses)) - but I wondered if there may be some simple way to implement this, perhaps with a `@ClassMethod`?

I have not had cause to use one before, so I am not sure if that would offer a solution.

Comment: Can't you just override `put()` and provide the extra constraint logic there?

Comment: How would that be done - could it still call the 'original' `put()` after the appropriate check? I'm not up for re-implementing the whole thing, and one probably shouldn't, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would override `.put()` to do your special validation before continuing with the regular (ie. super-class' .put):

```
class user(db.Model):
    ...
    def put(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.isFromUK:
            if not self.fromCountry:
                raise ValueError("Need fromCountry if isFromUK..")
        super(user, self).put(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `super` was what was missing from my know-how - thanks!